# How To Implement onClickListener for FloatingActionButton on Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I'm on fragment and I want to create an event listener on my floating button.

When I run my app I have the logcast for display the FloatingActionButton button. But when I click on it. I don't have any log.

So here is my code :

```java
public class FragContact extends Fragment {

    public FragContact() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton myFab = (FloatingActionButton) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
        Log.i("Info", myFab.toString());

        myFab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.i("Info", "onClick: here");
            }
        });

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact, container, false);
    }
}
``
```

Comment: You need to `return view;`, the instance you inflated and set the listener on. As you have it now, you're returning a completely separate instance of that layout, one which doesn't have your listener set.

Comment: Ok I don't know that, Thanks It work ^^